# how to use left outer join in hibernate using hibernate query language

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, join

hi i am trying to execute the hql query using left outer join it is thowing exception as org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: on near line 1, can pls tell me what is worng in this query

select * from CreditCardDetails cred left outer join CustomerHistory custHist on cred.creditCardDetailsId=custHist.creditCardDetailsId and custHist.cardA=0000

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have an association named `history` that relates the entity `CreditCardDetails` to `CustomerHistory`.

```
from CreditCardDetails cred 
left outer join cred.history custHist 
with custHist.cardA=0000
```

Comment: thx for reply .. its throwing ...for the above query org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! i

Comment: That's because you are missing an association between the two entities CreditCardDetails and CustomerHistory. HQL requires such a path in order to be able to execute this query (I updated the query to show how it's done).